# Why do fonts in Debian not look as beautiful as in Ubuntu

Tags: debian, fonts, fontconfig

I changed my OS from Ubuntu to Debian but I found that fonts do  not look as beautiful as they used to anymore.

Especially in stackexchange, every character grows thick and bold and not smooth. How can I improve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the fonts would likely improve this situation. Changing the overall theme being used can be controlled through `gnome-tweak-tool`.

```
$ gnome-tweak-tool
```

*screenshot*

[image: ss of gtt]

Changing the theme might also help too. You can check out this guide if you'd like to change the theme, titled: [Use Custom Theme in GNOME Shell 3.6 (Ubuntu 12.10)](http://www.fandigital.com/2012/10/use-custom-theme-in-gnome-shell-36.html). This approach should work for Debian as well as other GNOME 3 based distros.